# Create a count-consecutive variable which resets to 1

Tags: r

I have a dataset like the following, where "group" is a group variable. I want to count the number of 'next' days by group, but if it is not the next day I want the count to reset to one (as shown in the "want" column). Then, I want to return the max number of the "want" column (as in want2). Suggestions would be appreciated!

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
               date=c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-09", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-12"),
               want=c(1,1,2,3,1,2,1),
               want2=c(3,3,3,3,2,2,2))
```

bonus part 2: Thank you for all the feedback, it was extremely helpful. Is there a way to do the same with an added condition? I have a binary variable and I also want my count to reset when that variable==0. Like so:

```
#   group       date binary want
#1      1 2000-01-01      1    1
#2      1 2000-01-03      1    1
#3      1 2000-01-04      1    2
#4      1 2000-01-05      0    1
#5      2 2000-01-09      1    1
#6      2 2000-01-10      0    1
#7      2 2000-01-12      1    1
#8      3 2000-01-05      1    1
#9      3 2000-01-06      1    2
#10     3 2000-01-07      1    3
#11     3 2000-01-08      1    4
```

I have tried akrun's suggestion which worked very well without the binary var, I tried to modify it adding the binary var as part of cumsum but I get errors:

```
df %>% group_by(group) 
%>% mutate(wantn = rowid(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(date)) !=1 & binary==1)))
```

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you shape your data so that `$date` is really a date, not just a string. With that, it'll be much easier to calculate the difference (in days) between one row and the next. Have you tried anything? For instance, are you using `data.table` or `dplyr` or just sticking with base R?

Comment: have dplyr and tried data.table. It is as a date variable, I just posted as a string for the example

Comment: biostatguy12, got it ... but please present representative data when asking a question; many questions are often difficult because the asker does not know about `Date` class (etc), so we often wonder at what level things are breaking down in the problem. (An easy remedy would be to add `as.Date(...)` in your `date=` row. Perhaps not critical now with akrun's excellent answer, but in the future, clarity is good. Other than that, nice sample data, thanks for keeping it small!)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to group by 'group', then use `diff` on the `Date` class convered 'date', create a logical vector and use `cumsum` to replicate the results in 'want' ('wantn') and then with the 'wantn', apply `max` on it

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(wantn = rowid(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(date)) !=1))), 
          want2n = max(wantn))
# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   group [2]
#  group date        want want2 wantn want2n
#  <dbl> <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <int>  <int>
#1     1 2000-01-01     1     3     1      3
#2     1 2000-01-03     1     3     1      3
#3     1 2000-01-04     2     3     2      3
#4     1 2000-01-05     3     3     3      3
#5     2 2000-01-09     1     2     1      2
#6     2 2000-01-10     2     2     2      2
#7     2 2000-01-12     1     2     1      2
```

or if we want to not use `rowid`, then create the grouping variable with `cumsum` and get the sequence

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    group_by(group2 = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(date)) !=1)), add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(wantn = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(want2n = max(wantn)) %>%       
    select(-group2)
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks for the response. This is helpful, however if group 2 had an additional observation with date==2000-01-13, the method breaks down and doesn't reset to 1 (at observation 7), and then want2n is not what I want:

Comment: ```
df<-data.frame(one=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
               date=c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-09", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-12", "2000-01-13"),
               want=c(1,1,2,3,1,2,1, 2),
               want2=c(3,3,3,3,2,2,2, 2))

df1<-df %>%
  group_by(one) %>%
  mutate(wantn = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(date)) ==1)), 
         want2n = max(wantn))
```

Comment: beautiful. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @akrun I am just curious, I want to use this method but what if instead of "date" I had a numeric var (date2)? Such as in:
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
               date=c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05", "2000-01-09", "2000-01-10", "2000-01-12"),
               date2=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,0),
               want=c(1,1,2,3,1,2,1),
               want2=c(3,3,3,3,2,2,2))

I'd like to use it without the diff() function if possible

Comment: @biostatguy12  For `numeric` the `diff` would work.  If you don't want to use `diff`, do a subtraction with `lag` of the variable

Comment: even if that numeric var is just binary 1's and 0's??

Comment: @biostatguy12  You can do that on any numeric column

Comment: @biostatguy12  I guess your new question is related to this, right.  I added a solution there

Comment: is there a way to make that code conditional on another binary value (i.e. reset to 1 when some variable "binary" is 0?) For example:
 df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(wantn = rowid(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(date)) !=1 & binary==1)))

Comment: @biostatguy12 can you please update with an example or post as a new question

Comment: @biostatguy12 sorry didn't check the update here.  I saw your new question post

Comment: no problem! It's a little different but should get me what I need

Comment: say I have a date variable with time, instead of using a difference of one day can I make the difference a range from 24 - 48 hrs? so instead of ```diff(as.Date(date)) !=1)``` could I: ```diff(date) <86400 & diff(date)>172800) ```(in seconds when date is POSIxct)? Doesn't seem to work

Comment: @biostatguy12  I think it depends on what the `diff` output is.  We can't specify the `unit` in `diff`, but if we use `difftime`, it is flexible as the `unit` can be specified