# Counting consecutive days but maintaining the count on the same day

Tags: r

I have a follow up question to this: [Create a count-consecutive variable which resets to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293432/create-a-count-consecutive-variable-which-resets-to-1)

Say I have:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1,1,2, 2, 2, 2), 
               date=c("2000-01-01 11:00:00", "2000-01-03 11:00:00", "2000-01-04 11:20:00", "2000-01-04 14:20:00", "2000-01-05 11:40:00", "2000-01-09 12:20:00", "2000-01-09 13:20:00", "2000-01-10 12:20:00", "2000-01-12 16:20:00"),
               want=c(1,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,1),
               want2=c(3,3,3,3, 3,2,2,2,2))
```

I now have dates with times and I want to count observations that were >= 24 hours after the day before but not 48 hours after, while maintaining the count when an observation occurs on the same day. Notice that the 'want' column gives me the current count of consecutive days and 'want2' gives the max amount of consecutive days by group.

```
  group                date want want2
1     1 2000-01-01 11:00:00    1     3
2     1 2000-01-03 11:00:00    1     3
3     1 2000-01-04 11:20:00    2     3
4     1 2000-01-04 14:20:00    2     3
5     1 2000-01-05 11:40:00    3     3
6     2 2000-01-09 12:20:00    1     2
7     2 2000-01-09 13:20:00    1     2
8     2 2000-01-10 12:20:00    2     2
9     2 2000-01-12 16:20:00    1     2
```

This was an elegant solution but I can't seem to apply it to the added time and same day problem:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(wantn = rowid(cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.Date(date)) !=1))), 
          want2n = max(wantn))
```

it especially gets tricky when I have three or more observations within 24 hours, because I still would want to use the first observation in that sequence of three same days if an observation happens 24 hours after the first but not second or third (i.e. like observation 3, 4 and 5 in the example I've posted, I want observation 5 to be counted after observation 3 [2->3, not resetting to 1 based on observation 4]). Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: No because 6 to 8 is 24 hours after (still want to include that count) but as you can see the 'same day' observation of 7 and 8 causes some problems

Comment: It is not clear to me how you get the `want` column. Why it is 1 at row 2 and 2 at row 3? Can you explain?