# Create a count consecutive variable which resets to 1 based on POSIXct date

Tags: r

Follow up to this: [Create a count-consecutive variable which resets to 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58293432/create-a-count-consecutive-variable-which-resets-to-1)

and the solution worked great. Now I have below, where date is POSixct:

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
               date=c("2000-01-01 00:00:00", "2000-01-03 00:00:00", "2000-01-04 07:07:40", "2000-01-05 09:09:00", "2000-01-09 00:00:00", "2000-01-10 14:00:00", "2000-01-11 13:00:00"),
               want=c(1,1,2,3,1,2,1),
               want2=c(3,3,3,3,2,2,2))
library(anytime)
df<-df %>% mutate(date = anytime::anytime(str_c(date, sep= ' ')))
```

```
  group                date want want2
1     1 2000-01-01 00:00:00    1     3
2     1 2000-01-03 00:00:00    1     3
3     1 2000-01-04 07:07:40    2     3
4     1 2000-01-05 09:09:00    3     3
5     2 2000-01-09 00:00:00    1     2
6     2 2000-01-10 14:00:00    2     2
7     2 2000-01-11 13:00:00    1     2
```

I want to begin counting when the 'next day' is after 24 hrs but before 48 hrs.

Trying this without success, because I think the diff function gives me a result in seconds:

```
df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    group_by(group2 = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(date)<86400&diff(date)>172800))), add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(wantn = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(want2n = max(wantn)) %>%       
    select(-group2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, `difftime()` is a better choice than `diff()` because the units can be specified.

If I understand correctly, a sequence of `POSIXct` timestamps is considered consecutive if the time difference is 24 hours or more but less than 48 hours.

The code below reproduces the expected result for the sample dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(want = difftime(date, lag(date, default = date[1L]), units = "days") %>% 
           floor() %>% 
           equals(1) %>% 
           not() %>% 
           cumsum() %>% 
           data.table::rowid(),
         want2 = max(want))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 4
> # Groups:   group [2]
>   group date                 want want2
>   <dbl> <dttm>              <int> <int>
> 1     1 2000-01-01 00:00:00     1     3
> 2     1 2000-01-03 00:00:00     1     3
> 3     1 2000-01-04 07:07:40     2     3
> 4     1 2000-01-05 09:09:00     3     3
> 5     2 2000-01-09 00:00:00     1     2
> 6     2 2000-01-10 14:00:00     2     2
> 7     2 2000-01-11 13:00:00     1     2
> ```

#### Explanation

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(delta = difftime(date, lag(date, default = date[1L]), units = "days"))
```

returns

> ```
> # A tibble: 7 x 5
> # Groups:   group [2]
>   group date                 want want2 delta         
>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <drtn>        
> 1     1 2000-01-01 00:00:00     1     3 0.0000000 days
> 2     1 2000-01-03 00:00:00     1     3 2.0000000 days
> 3     1 2000-01-04 07:07:40     2     3 1.2969907 days
> 4     1 2000-01-05 09:09:00     3     3 1.0842593 days
> 5     2 2000-01-09 00:00:00     1     2 0.0000000 days
> 6     2 2000-01-10 14:00:00     2     2 1.5833333 days
> 7     2 2000-01-11 13:00:00     1     2 0.9583333 days
> ```

By rounding down to the next lower integer (`floor()`), the logic for the `Date` case can be used.

#### Data

```
library(magrittr)
df <- data.frame(
  group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  date = c(
    "2000-01-01 00:00:00",
    "2000-01-03 00:00:00",
    "2000-01-04 07:07:40",
    "2000-01-05 09:09:00",
    "2000-01-09 00:00:00",
    "2000-01-10 14:00:00",
    "2000-01-11 13:00:00"
  ) %>% lubridate::as_datetime(),
  want = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1),
  want2 = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2)
)
```